# Decrease the length of headers with help of target_include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── log
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   ├── log.h
│   │   └── src
│   │       ├── log.cpp
│   └── main.cpp
```

In log.cpp I am usng `#include "../include/log.h"`  and in main.cpp I amd using `#include "include/log.h"`

I want to use `#include "log.h"`

I read that **target_include_directories** can help me.

How can I apply it to my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(Logger)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

#include_directories(log/include/) -- I used this, but I want to use target_include_directories

add_library(log_lib log/src/log.cpp)

add_executable(demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo log_lib)
```

Comment: IMHO, don't put paths in `#include` statements.  In my experience, header files can move.  Projects can reside in different sandboxes.  For example, I use "\sandboxes" while my teammate uses "\asandbox".  Let the build utility specify the search folders for the header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the target and then use the name as the first argument for `target_include_directories`

```
add_library(log_lib log/src/log.cpp)
target_include_directories(log_lib PUBLIC log/include)
```

worry about `INTERFACE` vs `PUBLIC` vs `PRIVATE` after you've got it all working and you want to understand it better. (This option transitively affects targets that depend on your library).

Comment: I  added  ```target_include_directories(log_lib log/include)``` but I have error
target_include_directories called with invalid arguments

Comment: `worry about INTERFACE/PUBLIC/PRIVATE after you've got` - well, no, you have to use one of them.

Comment: @KamilCuk: *slaps forehead* Yeah you're right. My memory lied to me and told me that it was `PUBLIC` by default.

Answer (score 1):

The line below helped

```
target_include_directories(log_lib PUBLIC log/include)
```